# .htaccess redirect issue on RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have any `http://www.mycom/api/*` route to the `mycom/api/index.php` file

```
RewriteEngine On
#1 
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z]+)  /mycom/api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

cause Internal Server Error

```
#2
RewriteRule ^/api/([a-zA-Z]+)  /mycom/api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
# 3
RewriteRule ^mycom/api/([a-zA-Z]+)  /mycom/api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

2 and 3 don't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the real url for index.php?
http://www.mycom/api/index.php or http://www.mycom/mycom/api/index.php ?

in the first case try this:

```
RewriteRule ^api(/.*)? /api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if it's the second

```
RewriteRule ^api(/.*)? /mycom/api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

BTW, do you need both the original query string and the mode parameter?

Comment: It's the second one.   RewriteRule ^api(/.*)? /mycom/api/index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]   caused Internal Server error.

Comment: then the problem will be somewhere else. it works for me for a url like `/api/asdf?foo=bar` it calls `index.php` with both _mode_ and _foo_.